# Parse using XMLDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using 'XMLDictionary' to parse xml. In one case I am getting the following dictionary(after converting NSData response to NSDictionary using 'dictionaryWithXMLData')

```
{
"__name" = "soap:Envelope";
"_xmlns:soap" = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
"_xmlns:xsd" = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";
"_xmlns:xsi" = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
"soap:Body" =     {
    GetPublicationsListResponse =         {
        GetPublicationsListResult = 0;
        "_xmlns" = "http://questbase.org/";
        publicationsList = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?>\n<publications>\n  <publication>\n    <pin>4533-1490-8280</pin>\n    <title>Unsecure Assessment</title>\n    <isSecure>0</isSecure>\n  </publication>\n  <publication>\n    <pin>5123-4751-0595</pin>\n    <title>Secure Assessment</title>\n    <isSecure>1</isSecure>\n  </publication>\n</publications>";
        studentID = "4795e7fc-5c98-4ec4-a155-5f719f14ef3e";
    };
};
```

}

Here, object for key publicationList is in xml and I am stuck trying to convert it into NSDictionary. Plz help.

Original xml request made was in the form:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <SecurityHeader xmlns="http://questbase.org/">
      <Password>string</Password>
    </SecurityHeader>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <GetPublicationsList xmlns="http://questbase.org/">
      <accountName>string</accountName>
      <userName>string</userName>
      <password>string</password>
      <ipAddress>string</ipAddress>
      <userAgent>string</userAgent>
    </GetPublicationsList>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

and the response is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetPublicationsListResponse xmlns="http://questbase.org/">
      <GetPublicationsListResult>int</GetPublicationsListResult>
      <studentID>guid</studentID>
      <publicationsList>string</publicationsList>
    </GetPublicationsListResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: That looks a bit like JSON, but not quite.  It seems to following similar encoding rules, but the first thing is to write some code that will decode that text into an object model so you can access the values.  That decoding will involve unescaping of those escape-sequences etc.  So tell is what format that is and what specifications cover its format?

Comment: @Droppy I am new to ios. Can't figure out what u r asking for. Still edited my question so it helps u to find out a solution.

Comment: Ah, so what you showed in your question was the output shown during debugging?  Might be useful to mention that.